# Extract number from a character string, if it is followed by certain characters in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a dataframe with a variable that contains food quantities in different measurement units. The dataframe contains ~11000 observations.

Let me give you this example: 
"10gr peterselie, 7 Grams look, 5g kruiden en 400GRAMM bouillon, 2 tbsp olive-oil, 1oz ketchup, 20 grapes, 1 gelbe Paprika"

I found a way to extract the numbers and sum them up, using this function:

```
sum_numerics <- function(x) {

  # Grab all numbers that appear 
  matches <- str_match_all(x, "[0-9]+")

  # Grab the matches column in the list, transform to numeric, then sum
  sapply(matches, function(y) sum(as.numeric(y)))

}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to extract all food quantities that are in grams and write them into a new variable to sum them up in the next step. I spend some time looking for ways to do this and spend some time solving the problem with the [regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/teYu2F/1), but I can't find a working solution and I really can't figure out how to write working regex-functions. Shame on me!

User "Max Teflon" provided a possible solution that looks, after some more investigation, like this:

```
get_gramms <- function(x) {

# Grab all numbers that appear
str_extract_all(x, "([0-9]+\\s?([gG]|[gGrRaAmM]{5,6}|[gGrRaAmM]{2}))") %>% # any number followed by an optional space and a small/capital g%>%

unlist() %>%

str_remove_all('[[:alpha:]]') %>% # a vector is what we want

str_trim() %>% # remove all trailing whitespaces

as.numeric() # change to numbers

}

x %>%
mutate(var = map(var,~get_gramms(.))) %>%
mutate(var = map_dbl(var,~ifelse(length(.)>0,sum(.),NA)))
```

I think his answer is close to solving my problem, but it still returns wrong values, for example for "1 gelbe Paprika".

Looking forward to new ideas, solutions!

Comment: You want 10,7,5,400?

Comment: Hey Nelson, yes I want to extract each number that is followed by g, gr, grams, gramm or however a person could indicate gramms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below, using `gsub()` + `regmatches()` + `gregexpr()` from base R

```
r <- sum(as.numeric(gsub("(\\d+).*",
                         "\\1",
                         unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\d+\\s?(g|gr|grams|gram)\\b",s,ignore.case = T))))))
```

such that

```
> r
[1] 422
```

**DATA**

```
s <- "10gr peterselie, 7 Grams look, 5g kruiden en 400GRAMM bouillon, 2 tbsp olive-oil, 1oz ketchup"
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to the manipulation along a column, maybe you can do it like below

```
f <- Vectorize(function(s) {
  sum(as.numeric(gsub("(\\d+).*",
                      "\\1",
                      unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\d+\\s?(g|gr|grams|gram)\\b",s,ignore.case = T))))))
}
)

df <- within(df, y <- f(x))
df <- within(df, y <- ifelse(y==0,NA,1))
```

Comment: Solves my problem, but I think it is not enough to look for small and capital g, because in some rows there could be something like "20 Grapes".

Comment: @SebasSchu I updated my answer so you can try if it works well

Comment: Because my dataset has ~11000 observations, I need something that returns NA, if there are no information in grams within the character-string.

Comment: @SebasSchu My code with return with 0 when nothing found. In that case ,you can replace `0` by `NA`, e.g., `r <- ifelse(r==0,NA,r)`

Comment: If I use it to mutate a new variable it returns the sum for all entries I guess. I did something like this: df$y <- sum(as.numeric(gsub("(\\d+).*",
                                         "\\1",
                                         unlist(regmatches(df$x, 
                                                           gregexpr("\\d+\\s?(g|gr|grams|gram)\\b", 
                                                                   df$x,  
                                                                    ignore.case = T))))))

Comment: @SebasSchu no, you cannot use the code that way, see my updates in "EDIT" for your updated information

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas! Your function perfectly does the job, even in critical cases like "1 gelbe Paprika"!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a look-ahead assertion and remove the whitespaces afterwards:

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- "10gr peterselie, 7 Grams look, 5g kruiden en 400GRAMM bouillon, 2 tbsp olive-oil, 1oz ketchup"

sum_numerics <- function(x) {

  # Grab all numbers that appear 
  str_match_all(x, "[0-9]+\\s?(?=[gG])") %>% # any number followed by an optional space and a small/capital g
    unlist() %>% # a vector is what we want
    str_trim() %>% # remove all trailing whitespaces
    as.numeric() %>% # change to number
    sum() # sum it up

}
sum_numerics(x)
#> [1] 422
```

Or, if you just want to get all the numbers and use them afterwards:

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- "10gr peterselie, 7 Grams look, 5g kruiden en 400GRAMM bouillon, 2 tbsp olive-oil, 1oz ketchup"

get_gramms <- function(x) {

  # Grab all numbers that appear 
  str_match_all(x, "[0-9]+\\s?(?=[gG])") %>% # any number followed by an optional space and a small/capital g
    unlist() %>% # a vector is what we want
    str_trim() %>% # remove all trailing whitespaces
    as.numeric() # change to numbers
}
get_gramms(x)
#> [1]  10   7   5 400
```

Note that the whitespace can not be put into the assertion since it is optional and an assertion needs a fixed length.

Comment: Thank you Max, your solution helps a lot, even though it does not completely provide the result I'm looking for. If I apply this function to a variable I want all numerics and the following unit (g, gr, GRAMM, whatever) per row.

In the case of my example I'm looking for this in y: "10gr 7 Grams 5g 400GRAMM"

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your function-name. If you do only want to get the numbers pre-sum, just remove the `%>% sum()` part in the code above. Is that the solution you are searching for?
I edited the code approprately

Comment: Thank you Max, your answer solves the problem quite well, except that I need the function to return NA, if there are no values in x that match. Otherwise I get an error when using the function to mutate a new variable y, that the columns don't have the same length.

Comment: So you want to turn your character input to a vector in the appropriate length (in your example  6?)
This is not really the scope of your question. It would be helpful if you could add the result you are expecting from your example to your question. Am I right to think, that you expect `10, 7, 5, 400, NA, NA` as your output? Do you want to parse only dutch recipes or other languages as well? If the latter, the inconsistent separation with ands (en) and commas could complicate things.

Comment: Sorry Max, to clarify: The string above is just an example. I have a dataset that consists of ~11000 observations and one variable contains information like the one I used as an example. I want to extract all values in grams, but if there are none, it should return NA for this observation. Is that understandable?

Comment: Just to be sure I do really get you now, you have got  ~11000 observations of one variable and each observation could contain a mention of a weight in grams, or no mention at all? Is it possible to have more then one mention in one observation?

Comment: This is correct. There might be observations which do not contain information at all, observations which contain information only in oz. And there are a lot of observations that contain information with mixed measurement units, like in my example above. For those observations which do not contain information in grams, the function should return NA. For those observations that contain information it should either take the information in grams and be able to write them in a separate variable, or sum them up directly. In the end I would like to be able to: df %>% mutate(y = function_name(x)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206025/discussion-between-sebasschu-and-max-teflon).

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat ugly but we can use:

```
sum(as.numeric(unlist(sapply(strsplit(my_string,","),
        function(x) stringr::str_extract_all(gsub("\\s","",x),
                "\\d+(?=[gG][rams]?)")))))#credit to ThomasisCoding(learnt something new)
[1] 422
```

Data:

```
my_string<-"10gr peterselie, 7 Grams look, 5g kruiden en 400GRAMM bouillon, 2 tbsp olive-oil, 1oz ketchup"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)

str_extract_all(my_string,"[0-9]+(?=[ ]{0,2}[gG])")[[1]] %>% 
  as.numeric()%>%
  sum()

[1] 422
```

if now you have a vector of strings:

```
mystrings <- c("10gr peterselie, 7 Grams look, 5g kruiden en 400GRAMM bouillon, 2 tbsp olive-oil, 1oz ketchup",
               "but also 5g of something and 10 Gr of other stuffs")

str_extract_all(mystrings,"[0-9]+(?=[ ]{0,2}[gG])") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x) as.numeric(x) %>%
           sum()
         )

[[1]]
[1] 422

[[2]]
[1] 15
```